# Is it possible for me to peek into what is done with an awaitable such as TaskAwaiter?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

As I'm trying to understand `async`-`await` at a deep level, I'm looking at the [documentation for the Task.GetAwaiter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
```

and it that's where I've basically reached the end of my rope because MSDN says

> **Remarks** This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code.

I was hoping to get a peek into the type of low-level "state machine" and how it uses the `TaskAwaiter` that is returned. Is there any source code that you can link me to look at? Or if there isn't, can you link me to source code of another language's low-level implementation of its equivalent of `async`-`await`?

Comment: What are you looking for? `GetAwaiter` doesn't implement the await functionality. *Any* class that has a method with this signature can be used with `await` - that's how Windows RT worked. .NET is open source anyway and just googling for TaskAwaiter.cs [returns the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs)

Comment: The state machine is generated by the compiler, not `TaskAwaiter`. You should probably look at the Roslyn source, although a decompiler is faster if you want to see the generated source

Comment: A relatively simple way is to use [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/) and look at the decompiled C#. Note the even for a trivial method the state machine is quite complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize and expand on what others said:

- If you want to read about how the state machine is generated by the compiler, look at [Jon Skeet's article series Eduasync](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/). Its disadvantage is that it was written while async-await was still being refined, so some of the information is going to be outdated (though it also contains articles on those changes, so putting that together should give you an accurate image).
- If you want to look at the code generated for a specific async method, you can use a decompiler, like the online [Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/) or Windows-based [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).
- You can also look at [the code in the C# compiler that performs the transformation to state machine](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/AsyncRewriter/AsyncMethodToStateMachineRewriter.cs). Though it might be hard to understand if you're not used to reading compiler code.
- You can also look at [the implementation of `TaskAwaiter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs).

Does that satisfy your curiosity?

Comment: Also, the C# language specification.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any source code that you can link me to look at?

The code is available on [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,9865ec4fb8abca74).

Comment: This is a comment

Comment: @mybirthname: No, I disagree: the OP asked for a link to a site where the source code could be viewed - which is provided here.

Comment: @code4life Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.